# CAST incorrectly casting float to varchar

Tags: sql, casting

Group,
I am sure this is user error somehow, but I am trying to CAST a column of numbers from a float to a varchar.  It works great for anything under 7 digits, but if the number is 7 digits it turns it into scientific notation or what ever they call that.  For example:

440000 displays 440000
1299125 displays 1.29913e+006

It looks like it is rounding 7 digit numbers up... which I am not sure why.

I am trying to convert it because I need to concatenated it to other fields that are all VARCHAR

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post the SQL you are using? I seem to remember that if you just cast to to varchar there is a default length for the varchar. You might want to look at convert rather than cast.

Comment: Here was my SQL and CustomerNumber is a float

CAST(CustomerNumber AS VARCHAR(15))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap your float within the str() function which, when given only one parameter, does have the side effect of dropping off everything to the right of the decimal point.

Problem:

```
select cast(cast(1234567890.01 as float) as varchar)

1.23457e+009
```

Answer without decimal:

```
select str(cast(1234567890.01 as float))

1234567890
```

Answer with decimal:

```
select str(cast(1234567890.01 as float),13,2)

1234567890.01
```

Comment: Seemingly have to do a LTRIM as well.

Answer (score 2):

`select cast(cast(@float as decimal(13,2)) as varchar)`